# Calculate slope on DEM

Tags: python, numpy

i have another problem.

I have to compute a slope for each cell in digital elevation model. The slope should be calculated for each center cell in a moving window with shape 3x3 cell and according tot he formula:

Slope=max|x9-xi|/A ; where values i are values from one to eight and value x9 is the center of a window. A is distance to the neighbouring cell midpoint. So for the cells that are diagonal to the center, the distance(A) is sqrt(2) multiplyed by resolution and for the others it's just equal to the resolution.

So what I don't know is how to write a code that will differ from cells that are diagonal and which not? I created an empty numpy array with 'no values' where I want to have slope values with the same resolution. I know I have to loop through rows and columns and that have to ignore the first and last rows and columns. 
My code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dem=np.loadtxt('dem.txt',dtype='int',delimiter=',')
(rows,cols)=np.shape(dem)
slope2=np.zeros((rows,cols))
   for r in xrange(1,rows-1):
    for c in xrange(1,cols-1):
        temp_win=dem[r-1:r+2,c-1:c+2]
        mid= temp_win[1,1]
        max_d=np.max([temp_win[0,0]],[temp_win[0,2]],[temp_win[2,0]],[temp_win[2,2]])
        max_1=np.max([temp_win[1,1]],[temp_win[1,0]],[temp_win[1,2]],[temp_win[2,1]])
        slope = (np.max([np.abs(mid-max_d)/np.sqrt(2)]),np.max([np.abs(mid-s1/np.sqrt(2))])
        slope_2 = slope[r,c]
```

Does anyone have any idea, I would really appreciate some help?

Comment: Use a GIS package instead of reinventing the wheel  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-slope-works.htm  but if you need to, emulate the code therein which there are variants or consult Burrough and McDonnel 1998, Principles of Geographic Information systems, Oxford Univ. Press ... or equivalent texts

Comment: You'd typically use `numpy.gradient` for this instead of iterating through each cell.  It will yield two 2D arrays with the y and x gradients that you can then use to calculate slope/aspect.  However it uses a very slightly different algorithm.

Comment: i edited my code now, but it says invalid syntax in the last 2 lines, so i still need some help please

Answer (score 0):

```
here is your 3 by 3 array, with its indexes
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        print((i, j) , end=' ')
    print()
    (0, 0) (0, 1) (0, 2) 
    (1, 0) (1, 1) (1, 2) 
    (2, 0) (2, 1) (2, 2)
```

to go diagonally you have to give a row or a column offset.
column_index = 2

```
    # diagonal (2,0)(1,1)(0,2)
column_index = 2
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        print((j + column_index,i), end=' ')
        column_index -=1
        break

(2, 0) (1, 1) (0, 2)
```

Comment: I have to do it a bit differently unfortunatelly, added some more code but syntax is incorrect, so still need help :/.

Answer (score 0):

max_1=np.max([temp_win[1,1]],[temp_win[1,0]],[temp_win[1,2]],[temp_win[2,1]])
should be
max_1=np.max([temp_win[0,1]],[temp_win[1,0]],[temp_win[1,2]],[temp_win[2,1]])
because 1,1 is mid

However it seems to me that your code won't work if mid's height is higher than some rounding nodes and lower than others, or if some are below 0.
If it what you are after, you should compare the 8 slopes and take the max of them.